# Unable to install Application Server Role

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, installation, iis, prerequisites

When I try to install Sharepoint 2013 on a new Windows 2012 R2 server, I encounter the following error with the Product Preparation Tool:

> Unable to install Application Server Role

[image]

I followed [a KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2765260) of Microsoft but without any result.

**Update:**
I manually installed all prerequisites. They are successfully installed, but the Product Preparation Tool still gives an error:

[image]

Comment: Do you have the disc/iso left for w2012 R2? Mount it to D, and add Net 3.5 from "Add features and roles" in Server Manager, and specify the sourcepath to " D:\sources\sxs".

Comment: For full support you should have installed with the SharePoint 2103 SP1 slipstreamed installation media, that is the first one officially supporting Server 2012R2

Comment: @RobertLindgren thanks. See my answer for the 'strange' thing I had to do to fix this.

Comment: Yeah that is a known workaround, but great that you found away around it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem:
In Windows Server2012 R2 ServerManagerCMD.exe does not exist, but the setup needs it. I made a copy of C:\Windows\system32\ServerManagerCmd.exe and renamed it to ServerManagerCMD.exe. After this 'fix' all prerequisites are successfully installed.

Comment: I skipped this solution a few times.  This was the magic trick that worked for me and solved my issues.

Answer (score 5):

You also need .NET Framework 3.5 installed. Check under features that its available.

[image]

If not, follow the guide [How to install .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2](http://www.danielclasson.com/install-net-framework-35-server-2012/)

Comment: Beat me to it. +1 :)

Comment: @Benny Skogberg check. Already installed.

Comment: @CitizenDB You will need to restart the server.

Comment: @user19952 done. no result

Comment: @CitizenDB See if [Troubleshooting an IIS Add Roles and Features error](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2012/12/03/troubleshooting-an-iis-add-roles-and-features-error.aspx) gives any clue...

Comment: @CitizenDB If you go to add roles and features, does it show that net 3.5 is installed?

Comment: @CitizenDB Last times i had problem with R2 i had to install this update as well to be able to progress. Worth a shot. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3005628

Comment: @user19952 installed, but no result.